# How do I emit a signal argument as an int instead of string?

Tags: signals, godot, strong-typing, gdscript, dynamic-typing

In Godot 3.3, I'm trying to make a Label respond to text entered through a LineEdit node. I connected the objects and can emit the signal, but the signal is only ever sent as a string, not as the int that I want. When I use the strong typing, I get the error "Cannot convert argument 1 from String to int.."

When I stop using strong typing and go back to weak typing, I have no errors. How do I emit a signal and make sure it's the data type I specified?

In the LineEdit node: `emit_signal("text_entered", text as int)`

In the Label node:

`func _on_text_entered(value :int):` <-This function header causes errors

`func _on_text_entered(value):` <-While this one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LineEdit`, "text_entered" is a build-in signal that the `LineEdit` uses. And when the `LineEdit` uses it, it sends `String`s (regardless of what you send when you use it).

When you send an `int`, there is no problem with the connected function taking `int`. But when `LineEdit` sends a `String` (as it does) the type does not match, and you get an error.

---

To answer the question on the title:

> How do I emit a signal argument as an int instead of string?

You are doing it. The code `emit_signal("text_entered", text as int)` is correct.

The problem is that `LineEdit` will send `String`s as well.

Of course, when you don't specify the type in the connected function, it can take both the `int` you send, and the `String` that `LineEdit` send.

---

Solution?

Declare a new signal. For example `number_entered`:

```
signal number_entered(number)
```

And emit that:

```
emit_signal("number_entered", text as int)
```

Since this is a custom signal you are declaring, `LineEdit` does not use it, and you would be in control on what you send. So you can connect your function that takes `int` to that signal, and it should give you no problems.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Godot is a complicated and unintuitive beast sometimes, but other times it's so smooth I can almost do stream-of-consciousness programming despite my inexperience. I guess I still need a lot more time with it.